# Are more mutexes more efficient?

Tags: multithreading, mutex

Suppose I'm using pthread in C++, suppose that I have N (e.g., N=10 or 100) independent variables need mutex protection. I can create N mutexes, one for each variable, or I can create a single mutex, to protect all these N variables. Suppose there is no dead-lock among them.

Of course, ideally having N mutexes is better since the waitings are less overlapped. But in practice, is this always true? Is there any other overhead (besides create/destroy) to maintain too many mutexes?

Comment: What "deadlock" means has to be learned the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the usage scenarios.

If you have a relatively large number of threads relative to the number of variables and/or there is a low rate of collisions trying to access the same variable, then you're better off using a large number of mutexes e.g. one per variable.

However if you have a small number of threads and/or there is a pattern of accessing the variables, you might be better off using fewer locks (even a single one) to reduce the cost of locking/unlocking the mutexes.

For the latter see how currently the mainstream implementations for Python and Ruby use a single lock per interpreter:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186889/why-was-python-written-with-the-gil

Answer (score 0):

Mutexes in general (pthreads/C++ std threads at least) are not expensive. What should be avoided is having two threads running in tight loops hammering the same lock - lock contention is expensive. Of course, you may also replace locks with atomics for some data.

If possible, try to partition your workload wisely to avoid the scenario where threads often wait long times for acquiring locks. Critical sections should be short, and preferaby avoid long or complicated  function calls or any other hard-to-analyze stuff inside the critical section.